# boost::locale::normalize() returns empty strings with ICU backend

Tags: c++, boost

Reduced problem code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

std::string fold_case_nfkc(std::string_view str)
{
    return boost::locale::normalize(boost::locale::fold_case(std::string(str)), boost::locale::norm_nfkc);
}

std::string normalize_nfkc(std::string_view str)
{
    return boost::locale::normalize(std::string(str), boost::locale::norm_nfkc);
}

std::string fold_case_nfc(std::string_view str)
{
    return boost::locale::normalize(boost::locale::fold_case(std::string(str)), boost::locale::norm_nfc);
}

std::string normalize_nfc(std::string_view str)
{
    return boost::locale::normalize(std::string(str), boost::locale::norm_nfc);
}

bool same_text(std::string_view left_, std::string_view right_)
{
    auto left{ fold_case_nfkc(left_) };
    auto right{ fold_case_nfkc(right_) };
    return left.compare(right) == 0;
}

int main()
{
    auto lbm = boost::locale::localization_backend_manager::global();
    auto s = lbm.get_all_backends();
    std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [](std::string& x){ std::cout << x << std::endl; });
    lbm.select("icu");
    boost::locale::localization_backend_manager::global(lbm);
    boost::locale::generator g;
    std::locale::global(g(""));
    auto test = u8"#접시가숟가락으로도망쳤다";
    std::cout << "input: " << test << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fold_case_nfkc: " << fold_case_nfkc(test) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "normalize_nfc: " << normalize_nfc(test) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is:

```
backends: icu posix std
input: #접시가숟가락으로도망쳤다
fold_case_nfkc: #접시가숟가락으로도망쳤다
normalize_nfc: #접시가숟가락으로도망쳤다
```

The output I actually get, if `icu` is the locale backend:

```
rmorales2005@tillie:~ % clang++ -o test locale_test.cpp -std=c++17 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_locale
rmorales2005@tillie:~ % ./test
backends: icu posix std
input: #접시가숟가락으로도망쳤다
fold_case_nfkc: #
normalize_nfc: #
```

(This system is FreeBSD 12.1, with clang version 8.0.1; `boost-libs` installed via ports)

If I use `posix`, or run the program on Windows, I get the expected output. But for `posix` this is only because it doesn't even support normalization.

How do I get this code to work with `icu` as the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be your terminal emulation playing tricks. On my Linux box, I get similar output when running from inside Vim, but running it through e.g. `od` or `xxd` shows that the bytes are there, and when redirecting to a file, it shows up correctly in an editor.

> Note though that on my c++20 compiler, the `char8_t const*` string (from `u8""`) cannot be streamed to `std::cout`, so I changed it to a regular `""` literal after making sure that my source file is utf-8 encoded.
>
> See the message: https://wandbox.org/permlink/BQnIsAzXMQVkE3Zn (compare with your compiler version of flags)

Here's a demonstruction:

### Showing The Missing Terminal Output

For all backends

[image]

### Showing The Hex Dump Filtered Output

For all backends

[image]

### Showing The Redirected Output

For all backends

[image]

Comment: I know this is merely pointing out symptoms, but it may lead you to seek the solution in the right spot (perhaps changing the terminal emulator or its config)

Comment: So in the "real" application I'm using this code in (a chat server based on IRC), using the `icu` backend still results in non-ASCII characters "disappearing". Here's a capture of an exchange involving an attempt to use a Unicode nickname: https://pastebin.com/BRRYwYSr

Server replied to the `NICK` command with response code `431` because it can't "see" the nickname `Νιάου` that was passed to boost::locale::normalize

Comment: OK. Following this lead, I had to modify `.login_conf` (FreeBSD) and specify a UTF-8 `charset` and `lang`. Restarting the SSH connection, now the test code produces correct output. Restarting my server now also results in correct output.